# I'm trying to call multiple parameters (self, other) in a __str__() function defined in a class but I keep getting an error

Tags: python-2.x

As stated above, I'm currently trying to print multiple values inside of a string function using the (self, other) process, but I keep getting this error:

TypeError: **str**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Here is my relevant code block:

```
def __str__(self, enemy):
                s = "{} vs {}\n\n".format(self.name, enemy.name)

                s += "Your move set: "
                for move in self.moves.keys():
                        s += move + " - "
                s += "\n\n"

                s += "Current health: {}\n\n".format(self.health)

                s += "Enemy health: {}\n\n".format(enemy.health)

                return s
```

This is how I'm calling the function, obviously with the fat trimmed out.

```
c1 = Fighter("Gunsmith" , "gunsmith.gif")

Main.character = c1

statsList.insert(END, str(self.character))
```

The code works if I delete enemy from the parameters and all other enemy.x parameters.

https://pastebin.com/7dWi2DpB
my full code, as its too detailed to link multiple parts.

heres the full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\CornTortilla\Desktop\Comp. Science\CSC132\Github\teamProject\Pi.py", line 197, in chooseGunsmith
    self.fightWindow()
  File "C:\Users\CornTortilla\Desktop\Comp. Science\CSC132\Github\teamProject\Pi.py", line 180, in fightWindow
    statsList.insert(END, str(self.character))
TypeError: __str__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: @IanPilipski I am calling it in a separate class. Ill edit the code into my post.

Comment: Basically you need to have another param of whatever class it's inside of as well.

Comment: Did you declare the __str__ function inside of a class of type character?

Comment: @IanPilipski ive linked the full code as its too much i feel to leave bits and pieces. the str is defined inside of a superclass, and the str function is being called inside of a different superclass. that, however, is not my issue. the concept of calling (self, other) simply isnt working

Comment: @usr2564301 full error has been edited in

Comment: `__str__` is [not supposed to have more arguments than `self`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). You want a regular function here.

Comment: @usr2564301 so how would I go about doing this as a regular function, and then calling that function in a separate class? i keep getting errors about certain values not being globally defined